# Is this a Waltz music?

Tags: piano, rhythm, dance

I am starting to playing a piano and I am new to a aclassical dance.

I was googling some Waltz songs, that I could play on a piano. I found *Beuty and the Beast* song, that was marked as a Waltz. But I was looking to the sheet music at the internet and I found that it is played on four times (4/4). Isn't the Waltz supposed to be three times song (3/4)?

Thank you very much for explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Beauty and the Beast” in its standard form is a pop ballad in 4/4 time, not a waltz. However, many times in musicals and musical theater they will do an alternate version of a song with a different feel and tempo. Sometimes it is for background music or a dance scene or a reprise. There is a waltz section in 3/4 time in this version of the song for a dance sequence. It starts a little past the 1 minute mark:

Like I said before though, this is not a typical version of this song.

Comment: (My favorite such re-metering is how *The Sound of Music* recasts "The lonely goatherd" as a ländler for the party scene.)

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out, the song itself is in 4/4 time. However, in the original animated movie, Beauty and the Beast are dancing a waltz — or at least something very waltz-like.

**Dance scene from the 1991 movie**

Waltzes are indeed in 3/4 time.

**Dance set to Johann Strauss's "Blue Danube" Waltz**

See also [John Belzaguy's answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/117358/70803) explaining how the song can be arranged into a waltz.